# MATLAB won't solve second order equation for n=/=0

Tags: matlab, differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the following:

```
y'' + n^2 *y = 0 with y(0)=y(H) = 0
```

This should return `y(x) = b*sin(2n*pi/H*x)`.
However, it matlab simply returns zero.
My code is

```matlab
syms y(x) H n
 ode2 = diff(y,x,2) + n^2*y == 0 ;
 cond1 = y(0) == 0 ;
 cond2 = y(H) == 0 ;
 cond = [cond1 cond2];
 dsolve(ode2, cond)
```

All this does it return zero. Think this is something very basic im missing here.

Comment: What is the problem, the solution is correct. The general solution with y(0)=0 is y(x)=b·sin(n·x), so you need n·H=k·pi for the second boundary, that is a special relation between n and H. Outside that only the zero solution exists.

Comment: The issue is that matlab wont return y(x) = sin(nx) for n=k*pi/H. As this is the non-trivial solution this is what i'm interested in

Comment: Matlab is no CAS, it has some CAS abilities added-on. So I would not expect miracles. You should look for the symbolic solution of eigenvalue problems, perhaps adding the condition that y'(0)==1 is already sufficient.